# Nesting IF ISNUMBER and SEARCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to sort out a logistics document sheet via text. This is my first attempt at anything remotely this complex in Excel and so have no clue of what I am doing wrong.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CAR",Data!C5)),"3 MASTER CARTON"),  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PAL",Data!C5)),"4 PALLET"),  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PIECE",Data!C5)),"1 PACKAGE"),  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SCAR",Data!C5)),"2 SHIPPING CARTON,"")
```

I want the following to happen: when I paste the information in the datasheet, the cells in the original sheet to only say either `1 PACKAGE`, `2 SHIPPING CARTON`, `3 MASTER CARTON`, or `4 PALLET CAR`.

The original information is as follows: the cells start with either: `PAL`, `CAR`, `PIECE`, or `SCAR` (example `CAR192`, it varies alot).

Comment: What's happening with your formula? Does it give an error? Does it return something, but not what you were expecting? Does it work sometimes but not others? Etc.  What's the ultimate idea with the formula, it's a little unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses were messed up. For example, you had a parentheses ending the IF statement too early:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CAR",Data!C5)),"3 MASTER CARTON")`

Delete the parentheses after "3 MASTER CARTON"

Try this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CAR",Data!C5)),"3 MASTER CARTON",  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PAL",Data!C5)),"4 PALLET",  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PIECE",Data!C5)),"1 PACKAGE",  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SCAR",Data!C5)),"2 SHIPPING CARTON","n/a"))))
```

*Note: extra spaces and carriage returns have been added to the formula for readability in this answer.  If you want to copy and paste, delete those.*

Comment: It works perfectly thank you so much for your help!